# Update Microsoft Access Table Field from Excel App Via VBA/SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I am successfully able to connect to database, but the problem is when it updates table field.  It updates the entire field in table instead of searching for ID number and only updating that specific Time_out Field.  Here is the code below, I must be missing something, hopefully something simple I have overlooked.

```
Sub UpdateAccessDatabase()

    Dim accApp As Object
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim id

    id = frm2.lb.List(txt)

    SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out = " & "Now()" & " WHERE "
    SQL = SQL & "((([Table3].ID)=id));"

    Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    With accApp
        .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Visitor_Info.accdb"
        .DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
        .Quit
    End With

     Set accApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Think the `id` local variable needs to be outside the double quotes when building the SQL statement - otherwise you are looking for an ID that is just the letters id

Comment: @barrowc yes you were right, that fixed things up, thanks in advance        _italic_**bold** '    SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out = " & "Now()" & " WHERE "
SQL = SQL & "((([Table3].ID)=" & id & "));"'

Comment: @barrowc actually, the right-side `id` is resolving to the id field.   Since the value in that field is always equal to itself, every row in the table is updated.  To look for an id whose value is the letters "id", you would need embedded quotes: `"...=""id""));"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the `id` is integer/long, you should modify the query as following:

```
SQL="UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out=#" & Now() & "# WHERE [Table3].ID=" & id;
```

In case the `id` is a text, you should modify the query as following:

```
SQL="UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out=#" & Now() & "# WHERE [Table3].ID='" & id &"'";
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: I tried to incorporate just 1 line of SQL but i was unable to get it to work, i will try things out again as it would be good to have another way of creating SQL query

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working Code below:

```
Sub UpdateAccessDatabase()
Dim accApp As Object
Dim SQL As String
Dim id
id = frm2.lb.List(txt)
***'modified lines below***
SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out = " & "Now()" & " WHERE "
SQL = SQL & "((([Table3].ID)=" & id & "));"

Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With accApp
.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Visitor_Info.accdb"
.DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
.Quit
 End With
 Set accApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: As I said, the problematic part is your SQL query erroneous syntax. See the extended answer providing a universal solution. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it accepted. Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

@alex

I was able to modify the query to your above mentioned SQL statement

i did have to remove a few (#,') from the statement in order for it work, but this is much cleaner

so here is another working example below

```
`Sub UpdateAccessDatabase()
 Dim accApp As Object
 Dim SQL As String
 Dim id
 id = frm2.lb.List(txt)
 ***'modified lines below***
 SQL = "UPDATE [Table3] SET [Table3].Time_out= " & "Now()" & " WHERE [Table3].ID=" & id & ""


 Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
 With accApp
 .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Visitor_Info.accdb"
 .DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
 .Quit
  End With
  Set accApp = Nothing

  End Sub`
```